# Netflix Curator Transaction error

Tags: java, transactions, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

While creating paths, I am getting NodeExists error in following code.

```
CuratorTransaction transaction = curatorFramework.inTransaction();
transaction.create().forPath("/foo")
        .and().create().forPath("/foo/123")
        .and().create().forPath("/foo")
        .and().commit();
```

So, in this it is trying to create foo again second time after it created first time.
Is there any way can I check the state of transaction when creating path so that in transaction /foo create exists, then it will not create again.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, it's not possible to check if you're trying to create a path twice. The reason is that you're committing the entire 'blob' as one transaction to zookeeper, which in a broad sense means that every operation will be done simultaneously.

There is at least two different ways of solving this, either you send every operation as individual operations, and in that case you can do:

```
if(curatorFramework.checkExists().forPath("/foo") == null){
  curatorFramework.create().forPath("/foo");
}
```

Or if it's important for your application that it uses transactions your application must control that it's not putting two conflicting operations in one transaction. By for example using a HashMap indexed on paths.

And on a side note, CuratorTransaction is deprecated so you should use [CuratorFramework.transaction()](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/CuratorFramework.html#transaction--) instead.